# Is there a way to use SFINAE to determine if a call to a templated function would fail due to the types provided?

Tags: c++, boost, sfinae, enable-if, lexical-cast

I have a templated class that I am using to provide a method that will use `boost::lexical_cast` to cast its `std::string` parameters to the type specified in the template, only if the lexical cast is possible. Currently to check if it's possible I'm simply checking to see if `operator>>` is defined for the type in question. Here is a contrived example that basically illustrates what I'm doing:

```
template <typename ArgType, class Enable = void>
MyHelperClass
{
   void Foo (ArgType arg&, std::string strArg) { } // not castable; do nothing
};

template <typename ArgType>
MyHelperClass<ArgType, boost::enable_if<boost::has_right_shift<std::istream, ArgType> >::type>
{
   void Foo (ArgType arg&, std::string strArg) {
      arg = boost::lexical_cast<ArgType>(strArg); // cast string arg to ArgType
   }
};
```

So far this works fine for my code: all of the types that would fail a lexical cast end up with the first version and all others end up with the second, at least for the types my code is using this on. What I'm worried about is that I'm basically making the assumption that as long as the target type is InputStreamable then lexical_cast will not fail. The [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html#boost_lexical_cast.synopsis.lexical_cast) for lexical_cast outlines some other requirements, which I should probably be checking as well but rather than creating a complex `enable-if` and use `mpl::and_` to string together a bunch of these conditions, I was wondering: is there a way to use SFINAE to just test directly whether that call to `lexical_cast` would fail for the types given, and match the specialized template only if it wouldn't fail?

I've only ever seen examples for testing the existence of a function or operator, but never to test if a call to a templated function with a given type would produce an error.

Comment: You could encapsulate the requirements into an extra `struct`. Also, what kind of "error"? Exception? Compile-time error?

Comment: This is tricky because the return type of lexical_cast<T>() is defined for all T, even if lexical_cast<T> would fail to instantiate.  So, the usual tricks don't work.

Comment: I would only hope to be able to catch compile-time errors. Encapsulating the requirements into a `struct` would maybe help clean up the code but it doesn't fix the problem that I'm making assumptions about the implementation of `lexical_cast`. I'm afraid Vaughn is right though and what I want to do isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not.  Because lexical_cast is defined for all T, SFINAE won't help you.  The fact that the body of lexical_cast() will fail to compile for certain types does not cause a substitution failure.  The best you can do is to try to predict the conditions that will cause the body to fail, as you have already been doing.

Comment: I had a feeling this was the case, but I just wanted to make sure. Thanks!